How do I use the existing yml CI along with dependabot yml?
I currently have an existing yml in a specific folder for CI build. Every time a PR (change) is checked in, we will trigger the CI build.
Now, how do I add or combine the yml for dependabot, considering that in the dependabot we have trigger set to none versus in the CI, we have trigger set to a specific branch ? Ideally, we only want to run the dependabot scan only one time a week. Is it achievable with the v2 dependabot ? Thank you.
azure-pipelines.yml
# ASP.NET Core

# Build and test ASP.NET Core projects targeting .NET Core.
# Add steps that run tests, create a NuGet package, deploy, and more:
# https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/dotnet-core
---
variables:
  - name: buildConfiguration
    value: Release
  - name: agentPool
    "${{ if or(eq(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 'dev'), eq(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 'main'), eq(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 'dev-ttcdbtst')) }}":
      value: "TTC Servers"
    "${{ else }}":
      value: Azure Pipelines
  - name: rootPath
    value: "./../../../"
  - name: projectPath
    value: "./../"
  - name: unitTestPath
    value: "./../../Api.Test"
  - name: workingDirectory
    value: "src/Api/Build"
trigger:
  - main
  - dev  
  - feature/*
jobs:
  - job: null
    displayName: Build and Publish Artifacts
    pool:
      name: $(agentPool)
      vmImage: ubuntu-latest    
    steps:    
    - checkout: self
      fetchDepth: 0
    - task: UseDotNet@2
      displayName: 'Install .NET 8 SDK'
      inputs:
        packageType: 'sdk'
        version: '8.x'
    - task: Bash@3
      displayName: 'Check what account is running'
      inputs:
        targetType: 'inline'
        script: 'whoami'
        workingDirectory: $(workingDirectory)
    - task: Bash@3
      displayName: 'Install Cake.Tool'
      inputs:
        targetType: 'inline'
        script: 'dotnet tool install --global Cake.Tool | echo "Already installed"'
        workingDirectory: $(workingDirectory)
    - task: Bash@3
      displayName: 'Execute dotnet cake command'
      inputs:
        targetType: 'inline'
        script: 'dotnet cake --rootPath=$(rootPath) --projectPath=$(projectPath) --unitTestPath=$(unitTestPath)'
        workingDirectory: $(workingDirectory)
    - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
      displayName: 'Publish Build Artifacts'
      inputs:
        PathtoPublish: 'artifacts'
        ArtifactName: 'Artifact'
        publishLocation: 'Container'

dependabot-pipelines.yml
#inputs options: https://github.com/tinglesoftware/dependabot-azure-devops/blob/main/extension/README.md
trigger: none
stages:
  - stage: CheckDependencies
    displayName: Check Dependencies
    jobs:
      - job: Dependabot
        displayName: Run Dependabot
        pool:
          vmImage: ubuntu-latest
        steps:
          - task: dependabot@2
            displayName: Run Dependabot            
            inputs:
              setAutoComplete: true

dependabot.yml
version: 2
updates:
  - package-ecosystem: 'nuget'
    directory: '/'
    target-branch: 'dev'
    open-pull-requests-limit: 15
    ignore:
        - dependency-name: 'Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.SqlServer'
    registries:
      - azure_artifacts
    schedule:
      interval: weekly
      # Check for npm updates on every Sundays
      day: "sunday"
      time: "09:00"
      timezone: "America/Los_Angeles"    
    # Labels on pull requests for security and version updates
    labels:
      - "npm dependencies"
registries:
  azure_artifacts:
    type: "nuget-feed"
    url: "https://xxx.pkgs.visualstudio.com/0497dd12-e7ca-49f7-999e-7f22d25e38c8/_packaging/TTCWebFeed/nuget/v3/index.json"
    token: "PAT:<PAT>"


Hi @HoangMinh, Good day to you. At your convenience, can you let us know how your pipeline schedule trigger works now? Hope the suggestion in my updated answer to configure schedule in web UI can resolve the issue from your side. Thx for the time and efforts. Have a lovely weekend.

Update
Based on the update, please double check the pipeline definition dependabot-pipelines.yml in the dev branch. The scheduled trigger for each branch only follows the branch filter in its own branch. You may go through this document for further investigations.
In addition, you may directly change pipeline trigger settings via web UI like in the image below, which could be more user-friendly.


You may create a new pipeline referencing the dependabot-pipelines.yml definition that uses the Scheduled triggers. Make sure the dependabot-pipelines.yml definition file exists in the expected branch.
Here is a sample YAML pipeline with weekly trigger upon new source code changes in dev branch, since the last successful scheduled run.
trigger: none

schedules:
- cron: 0 16 * * 0 # UTC
  displayName: Weekly Sunday Scan # friendly name given to a specific schedule
  branches:
    include:
    - dev # which branches the schedule applies to
  always: false # whether to always run the pipeline or only if there have been source code changes since the last successful scheduled run. The default is false.
  batch: false # Whether to run the pipeline if the previously scheduled run is in-progress; the default is false.
  # batch is available in Azure DevOps Server 2022.1 and higher

stages:
- stage: CheckDependencies
  displayName: Check Dependencies
  jobs:
    - job: Dependabot
      displayName: Run Dependabot
      pool:
        vmImage: ubuntu-latest
      steps:
      - task: dependabot@2
        displayName: Run Dependabot


Thanks @Alvin for pointing me to the right direction. However, the scheduler in his yml file is somehow not recognized by Azure, even though the file is validated with no issue. I had to modify it a bit, not sure what is wrong.
Here is my modified yml:
# ASP.NET Core

# Build and test ASP.NET Core projects targeting .NET Core.
# Add steps that run tests, create a NuGet package, deploy, and more:
# https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/dotnet-core
#inputs options: https://github.com/tinglesoftware/dependabot-azure-devops/blob/main/extension/README.md
trigger: none 
schedules:
- cron: 0 13 * * 0 # 1pm in UTC = 6/7am PST cron syntax defining a schedule
  displayName: weekly build on Sunday # friendly name given to a specific schedule
  branches:
    include: [ dev ] # which branches the schedule applies to
  always: true # whether to always run the pipeline at the scheduled time, even if there have been no changes
  batch: false # whether to run the pipeline if the previously scheduled run is in-progress; the default is false
jobs:
  - job: null
    displayName: Scan dependencies
    pool:
      name: Azure Pipelines
      vmImage: ubuntu-latest    
    steps:    
    - task: dependabot@2
      displayName: 'Run Dependabot'
      inputs:
        autoApprove: true
        setAutoComplete: true


Hi @HoangMinh, Thanks for the update. Would you edit your original post with the information, since it is not an answer actually? Besides, can you please double check if the YAML definition file above is from dev branch? The schedule triggers for each branch only follows in the definition file in its owner branch. That's to say if you edit the YAML definition file in main branch, it will not take effect to trigger the workflow for dev branch.
